# Regex match until first instance of certain character

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a url up until a special character however the regex I am using is match the last instance when I need it to stop after the first instance. What am I doing wrong?!

```
.+?(?=\")
```

To match everything until first `"`

However my result is below:

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You added the `"` into the consuming part of the pattern, remove it.

```
^.+?(?=\")
```

Or, if you need to match *any* chars including line breaks, use either

```js
(?s)^.+?(?=\")
^[\w\W]+?(?=\")
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FEKvy6/387). Here, `^` matches start of string, `.+?` matches any 1+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first `"` excluding it from the match because the "` is a part of the lookahead (a [zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

In the two other regexps, `(?s)` makes the dot match across lines, and `[\w\W]` is a work-around construct that matches any char if the `(s)` (or its `/s` form) is not supported.

Best is to use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
^[^"]+
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/FEKvy6/2). Here, `^[^"]+` matches 1+ chars other than `"` (see `[^"]+`) from the start of a string (`^`).

Comment: I am now using the code in PHP for a command line echo - echo shell_exec("cat /tmp/urls | grep -Eo '^[^\"]+'"); I'm not getting a result though any ideas I assume its because I havn't used a backslash somewhere but ive tried everything it seems

Comment: `grep -Eo '^[^"]+'` should extract the strings from the start of a line to the first `"` excluding it from the match. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/hvNZ1m).